# Is the Math.random() function actually a fractal?

Tags: javascript, canvas, random

I am following the quadtree tutorial from The Coding Train (YT), and I got my quadtree working and drawing! My problem is that the points in using Math.random()*canvas.width and Math.random()*canvas.height to create a random point on the canvas isn't giving me a random pattern of points, It's fractal (like the Sierpinski Triangle).

I've looked up the chaos game (thanks to Numberphile) and understand enough to know that Math.random() isn't working. Here is my code that is generating the points.

```
for(let i=0; i<100000; i++){
    var rx = Math.random()*canvas.width;
    var ry = Math.random()*canvas.height;
    let p = new Point(rx, ry, 2.5, i);
    qtree.insert(p);
}
```

If anyone knows an explanation that would help, am i using Math.random() incorrectly?  Is there a better way to get a random point inside a square?

EDIT:
This is the jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/muteman30/5b8mpfsc/5/

Comment: what is expected output of rx? `Math.random()` returns value between 0 to 1

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a `floating point number` between 0 and 1. So it does not give a `fractal`, which is something else entirely. But it could work I guess, since it creates a number between 0 and canvas.width. So the code shown should be correct. If the collection of points together form a fractal, you probably have an issue in code not shown.

Comment: Try this: `const getRandomInt = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;`

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the result (or a working snippet) ? I'm not sure what you mean exactly with "fractal"

Comment: hopefully this JSFiddle should work - https://jsfiddle.net/muteman30/5b8mpfsc/5/

Comment: Are you sure it's `Math.random()` fault and not `Quadtree` implementation feature?

Comment: It's definitely the Quadtree implementation:  try setting `capacity` to the total number of points and you get an even distribution.   Somehow once you divide, you are not putting any more points in the NE quadrant.

Comment: ooo yeah! thanks so much for point that out @AShelly !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your subdivide function:

```
    let neb = new Rectangle(b.x+b.w/2, this.y, b.w/2, b.h/2);
```

`this` should be `b`

Comment: Of Course! Thank you so much!